# Facebook/Instagram location id

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Hi i need to create aplication for android as my course work project for university. 
But in order to finish it i need to get INSTAGRAM  location id  using longitude and latitude. 
For instance i have Latitude and Longitude 40.752340, -73.979873 and i need to convert tham to Instagram location id.
I was just wondering is the are any ways i can get location id ?
i was using this method but it doesnt work anymore

https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search/?lat=40.758895&lng=-73.985131&access_token=ACCESS TOKEN

but every time i try to use it i see

{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "APINotAllowedError", "error_message": "This endpoint has been retired"}}

is there  any way i can get location id?

Comment: that old api is deprecated since a VERY long time, you should read the message and follow the link to the new api docs: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: this is the problem i couldn't find new working api for this even on their site. And previous api wasn't listed on their site as well but it worked for  some time

Comment: they limited some stuff, so if you don´t find it in the new api docs, it´s not possible.

Comment: i think it's probably  possible because there still a lot of instagram api which isn't listed on ther site but still working fine

Comment: keep in mind that apps may not stop working with the old api at the same time, it´s quite possible that this is a step by step process. again, if you don´t find it in the new api docs, there´s little chance that it will still work.